# numbers of pages don't appear on pdf printed

Tags: page-numbering

I created a document in latex. The numbers of pages appears on pdf, but I printed the pdf and numbers don't appear.

Somebody can help me ?

Example of one of my pages:

[image]

my preamble code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[lmargin=3.0cm,rmargin=2.0cm,tmargin=2.0cm,bmargin=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{  {fig/} }
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\onehalfspace 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage
\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Intro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the page numbers appearing so close to the margin that they cannot be printed by the printer?  This is the most likely explanation...

Comment: probably, but how I can check this problem ou change ?

Comment: Hard to tell without a MWE that illustrates your page geometry.

Comment: I edited my question with my code. Can you help me ? thanks

Comment: Try adding the `includefoot` to the existing options of [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) so that the footer is actually `2cm` from the bottom, rather than the footer being included in the 2cm bottom margin.

Answer (score 5):

By default, [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)'s margin settings exclude the header/footer. as such, even though you specify a top/bottom margin of 2cm, the distance from the page boundary to the first textual component would be less. To be more precise in terms of this placement, `geometry` provides the keys `includehead`, `includefoot`, and `includeheadfoot` to allow the user to include either the header or footer or both in the calculations for the margins. The following is taken from the [`geometry` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf):

[image]

Using your case as an example, the impression is that the 2cm bottom margin puts the page number outside the printing margin for the printer. Adding `includefoot` (at least, but perhaps `includeheadfoot`) to your `geometry` settings should push the footer into the printing region.